# Unable to instantiate GcmBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to create test app with GCM service, according to the Google manual https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#app

But when i receive message - I have this error:

> Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.example.testpushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testpushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testpushnotification-2.apk"],
>   nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testpushnotification-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I was looking for all same questions, but they have no solutions or solutions didn't help or they are deprecated.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.testpushnotification"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission android:name="com.example.testpushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testpushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testpushnotification.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.testpushnotification"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService"/>
</application>
```

And source code for GcmBroadcastReceiver in the com.example.testpushnotification package:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
```

And why Dex path contains differ package than my?

Please, how to fix it ?

**FIXED** Changed `<receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
             ..
            </receiver>`

to `<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
             ..
            </receiver>` (case sensetive)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

Add like this :

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.test.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It should be : **com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver** and not **.GCMBroadcastReceiver**

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: I think, if Android Dependencies wrong - i could not get registrationID. I tried this solution again, but it still not working. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I tried also add package name, but there is no result too.

Comment: You cannot add package name.You need to add com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 2):

I followed the developer.android tutorial: /google/gcm/client.html

My issue was I had "Android Dependencies" ticked under **Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export**.

List of appropriate libraries:

- Android 4.4.2
- Android Private Libraries
- android-support-v4

Hope this helps somebody out there!

This code was correct

```
<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.infostretch.iSOSAndroid" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same issue. But solved it, let me share my solution steps..

- I created a new package, then moved the BroadcastReceiver to that package.
- Add The receiver declaration TAG After the activity tag which is providing the GCM registeredID with proper package name.

my main problem was GcmBroadcastReceiver class which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver and that requires v4 library. I've added multiple libraries for some reasons, one of them contains v4, i just simply remove that v4 from that library. Add v7 as library to my application, then clean and run...then its works. Sorry for my bad english, i just share my experience to help.

Answer (score 0):

Mi Fix was to use the Manifest Editor Wizard to change the name of the service and receiver. Result was:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/journey_icon"
    android:logo="@drawable/journey_icon"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"           
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver         
        android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"         
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >         

        <intent-filter>              
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />              
            <category android:name="com.example.JourneyApp" />         
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Changed to

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/journey_icon"
    android:logo="@drawable/journey_icon"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"           
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver         
        android:name="journeyAux.GCMBroadcastReceiver"         
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >         

        <intent-filter>              
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />              
            <category android:name="com.example.JourneyApp" />         
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service android:name="journeyAux.GCMIntentService" />
```